# SSIS | All queries and Stored Procedures Returning DBNull

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I'm creating a SSIS package that will basically have a SQL Task that is using a Stored Procedure that will return a single string column.

The issue is that all queries I try, are returning this error:

**Error: The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User::varTEST" differs from the current variable type (Int32). Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.**

It seems my query is not returning values, when indeed if I use sql management studio to exec the stored procedure it returns values. I'm using the Full Result Set, and as a result name using 0 to map with my variable. I've tried simple queries and it seems everything is returning DBNull.

I've also tested the connection, and It's successfull.

Any ideas?

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Sorry if this comes off the wrong way but are you pointed to the same data in your SSIS package as your query in SSMS? Possibly a context issue.

Comment: Does your query return more than one row?

Comment: sometimes it returns 1 row. Other times it return more than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query that can return more than one row cannot be used to populate an SSIS variable of type Int32, nor of any type other than Object.

If your ExecuteSQL task is using the "Full Resultset" option, then you must map the result to an Object-type variable.

Comment: Thanks. How can I then use each row to send an email?

Comment: You would iterate through the object variable in either a foreach loop, or a script task.